# WebView onBackpressed() issue

Tags: android, performance, webview, onbackpressed

I have created an app opening a website in webView. It was working fine but few days back I'm facing a issue that when a user above android version 6.0 presses a back button webview closes. Searched it on the internet found that webview is disabled in certain android versions? Any Solutions for this? How Can I upgrade / resolve the issue?

Comment: Please provide some piece of code to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should override your Activity's [onBackPressed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method, as stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-webviews)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```